# Invalid handle exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have unit test that tests whether my functionality won't allow to use closed socket. So it looks somehow like this:

```
closesocket(sock);
int result;
result = getsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_TYPE, type, len);
if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    //write error etc.
```

On Windows platform call to getsockopt does not raise an exception "0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.". On Windows Phone ARM platform it raises an exception and while i can turn off the First-chance exception i cannot really turn off the uncaught exception.

Trying

```
try{
getsockopt();
}
catch(...)
{}
```

doesn't work. Is there a way I can silence this exception ?

**EDIT**

I would like to point out that I am first calling closesocket(sock) and later getsockopt() on purpose because I want to test whether my function that calls getsockopt() will reject such situation. And while on Windows I can run my tests smoothly because getsockopt don't throw exception, on Windows Phone ARM it does, making me to sit and wait for this call just to click continue.

Comment: First, silencing exceptions is a terrible pattern. Find the problem and fix it. Second, I'm pretty sure Window's SEH or .NET exceptions are not compatible with C++'s `catch(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Despite their name, these are not C++ exceptions but [SEH exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They are the Windows equivalent of Unix signals.

Receiving such an exception is akin to a segfault (SIGSEGV) : it's almost always wiser not to try and recover from it, but to prevent it from happening in the first place. Refer to `getsockopt`'s documentation to know how.

In the cases not covered by "almost always", you can resort to the compiler-specific [`__try`/`__except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx) structure to catch and handle SEH exceptions, if at all possible.

Comment: unfortunately __try/__except wont work for me: "cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding". Why it doesn't throw those exceptions on Windows platform ?

Comment: @Michal what about the preventive method ? You must be passing something to this function that it doesn't expect.